# Why is my dplyr::filter() command not working with error saying x` must be a vector, not a <ODBC_binary> object?

Tags: r, dplyr, rodbc

I have read in some data from an SQL server database using the `sqlFetch` function from the RODBC package. The data reads in correctly (as far as I can see). However when I try to apply a simple `dplyr::filter()` using the syntax:

```r
filtered_data<- original_data %>%
  filter(character_vector== "character I want to keep")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <ODBC_binary> object.
```

I assume this means the column I want to filter on is type ODBC_binary and so the function doesn't work. However I have checked the class of the column and it returns the class as 'character'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you create `original_data`? it seems clear that it's not a `data.frame`-like object, or at least `filter(.)` doesn't think that it is. Please [edit] your question and add the code you used to generate it into a [code block] (triple backticks, newline, code, newline, triple backticks).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the dataset was created by reading from an SQL table using an ODBC link.

Comment: I'm asking because i cannot reproduce your error with a few different things I've tried. We have no notion of what your data looks like or how it was created. You are hoping that somebody has seen the same error as you and might be able to give you a workaround. If you want a better chance of getting actionable help, there needs to be more information about `original_data`, its columns, their classes, etc. If you don't want to share how it was created, at least share some sample data, perhaps `dput(head(original_data))` into a [code block].

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error as well, in my case it was due to a different column in the data frame (not the filtered column) being of the 'ODBC_binary' datatype.  Try checking the datatypes of all your columns.